# Problems with rsh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I have problems calling a remote command by different users on different machines. This remote command shall be executed on one single machine and the rsh-session shall
be terminated immediately after successful execution of this command. Multiple users can execute this command at the same time.

I know that `rsh` is insecure, but this isn't an issue here.

My problem here is the configuration of the remote system in regard to privileges and location of the script.

Locally, the rsh command is simply called like this:

```
rsh $HOST -l $USER remote_command
```

Some concrete questions here:

- Do I need a special user (`$USER`) unlike root to execute the remote command?
- Which privileges should this user have?
- Only the privileges to execute the necessary commands and read and write the files that this commands use?
- In which directory should the script be located?  I would place it in `/usr/bin`, but I don't know if that's a good idea.

Comment: Don't put your scripts in `/usr/bin`, use `/usr/local/bin` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem think that *security does no matter* there,

Some concrete answer:

- *Do I need a special user ($USER) unlike root to execute the remote command?*

  Technicaly no, (regardless of security consideration.)
- *Which privileges should this user have?*

  The privilege level required  are only depending on what
  `remote_command` have to do.
- *Only the privileges to execute the necessary commands and read and write the files that this commands use?*

  So if all concern script and files at same conceptual level, I think
  the better way is to create an unprivileged user, with his `home`
  directory and put all files and script under this `home` directory.
- *In which directory should the script be located?*

  The best place is  `$HOME/bin/` (ensuring `$HOME/bin` is added to
  your `$PATH` variable, from your `.bashrc` or `.profile`.), the
  second best place, if this script have to be accessed by other users
  on same machine is `/usr/local/bin` (as this path is by default in
  standard `$PATH` assignation.

Comment: Thank you. Security isn't really important, because in my case, rsh shall only be used within a trusted network. However, the privileges should be restricted to the necessary. In this case, rsh is only used to call a script that executes a kill command to send a signal to some other process on the server. This "nudge" should happen as fast and reliable as possible. Unfortunately, I don't know any shell script command that uses UDP.